# Is key rotation mandatory in Cloud KMS?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-kms

Will KMS automatically generate new key versions after a while if I don't do it manually? If I create a key and use it for encryption (and not specify rotation period or next rotation time), will the same key last forever without creating new versions?

I remember reading it will do it automatically somewhere in the documentation a few days ago and now I can't find that page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no obligation to do rotation. If you don't specify a rotation schedule, your key won't change unless you manually rotate it.

If you do use rotation (either automatic or manual), old key versions will be available for decryption indefinitely unless you delete them.

The page you cannot locate may be [Key rotation  |  Cloud KMS Documentation  |  Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/key-rotation).

Comment: If you don't mind, can you tell me if there is a provision to specify a URL to be called when a key is "rotated"? We run our app on GAE and we need our secrets to be re-encrypted with new keys when new versions are generated and destroy old ones (so we also save on price).

Comment: There is not, but I will file a feature request. You could implement a cron job which, on some frequency, calls [projects.locations.keyRings.cryptoKeys.get](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.keyRings.cryptoKeys/get) and checks to see if the primary CryptoKeyVersion has changed, and if so, triggers re-encryption. (You could also use nextRotationTime to schedule this for automatic rotation, but polling will be robust to schedule changes and manual rotation.) Thanks for using Cloud KMS!

Comment: Thank you for that feature request! I'm wondering how your suggestion would scale since we plan to create an unlimited number of keys. But I will try it out next week, thanks for your reply.

Comment: Kumar, I'd be happy to provide you with a design consultation on your problem and how it can work with Cloud KMS. Can you email us at cloudkms-feedback@google.com? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for that, but I guess the only tiny problem left is re-encryption after key rotation and I have thought about a fix for it. We have only started working on the feature now and only plan to create around 10 keys for now, it will increase to thousands in near future. My initial idea was to develop a fully scalable and foolproof solution upfront, which isn't necessary for quite sometime. I will certainly contact that email in case we need your help in scaling.